# how to solve javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module with jdk11

Tags: java-11, javax.xml

I have updated my java project from jdk8 to jdk 11 and I face the following error:

```
javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module
```

Comment: Could be related to the java module system introduced in Java 9

Comment: yes sure but how to fix the issue